# Is there still reciprocity fee at Chile airport entry for US citizens? (after US Visa waiver)

Tags: us-citizens, us-visa-waiver-program, chile, fees-and-charges

After US Visa waiver program come into effect, do visitors from USA (US citizens) still have to pay reciprocity fee on entry in Santiago?

I am planning to visit Chile in late July of this year.

Comment: Heard from a US-citizen recently (within the past week) that you don't have to pay the reciprocity fee on entry to Chile anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chile has removed the reciprocity fee for US citizens, on the basis that the US has removed the need for (most) Chilean citizens to obtain a visa to enter the US via their entry into the Visa Waiver Program.